Create matrix from Series to count same numbers
I would like to convert a pandas Series into a matrix counting where the same value occurs. Basically the index and columns will be the same and the values in the series will be counted where they occur at the same index. It's hard for me to explain but this example should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve!



Index
Col Values




1
1


2
2


3
3


4
1


5
2



to



Index
1
2
3
4
5




1
1
0
0
1
0


2
0
1
0
0
1


3
0
0
1
0
0


4
1
0
0
1
0


5
0
1
0
0
1



I tried pivot tables, correlation functions but they didn't work for me (yet?).

You can compute the cross tabulation of the series index and values, then merge the result with its transposition:
data = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 2}
series = pd.Series(data)

crosstab = pd.crosstab(series.index, series)
matrix = pd.merge(crosstab, crosstab.T).set_index(crosstab.index).rename_axis(None)

   1  2  3  4  5
1  1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  0  1
3  0  0  1  0  0
4  1  0  0  1  0
5  0  1  0  0  1


Your code works for me very well. But I seem to get a en Error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 30 rows, received array of length 60

Seems unrelated to the data in your question and the code in my answer.
